# Keras most important features for text classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras, features, predictor-importance

I am working on a problem where I need to **classify phrases** in one of the two categories (let's A & B). I used the **Keras SepCNN model** (similar to [this](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/)) for that and it is giving me some results.

Now, I want to analyse the predictions and more specifically I want to know why the model classified a certain phrase in category A or B, **which set of features played an important role in labeling** that phrase as category A or B?

I am not sure if this is even possible to do but need inputs on how to approach this.

```
#----Model Structure for your reference--
Vectorize text (tfidf)  
SelectKBest features (using scikit-learn feature_extraction)  
Fit the model  
Predict on test set*
```

I looked on the internet and found nothing helpful. It would be very helpful if someone can point me the right direction.
I also explored eli5 library but that does not seem to work for Keras SepCNN model (at-least I could not get it to work, let me know if anyone has used successfully it?)

Comment: How about shap's DeepExplainer? https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#shap.DeepExplainer

Comment: @SeanOwen, didn't know something like this exists for NNs too. Will look at it. Thanks